# Yii2 per content visibility depending on role

Tags: permissions, visibility, yii2

We have used [RBAC](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#role-based-access-control-rbac) to implement simple role based permissions for CRUD, but now we need to also add a 'visibility' functionality which makes it possible to limit content visibility (R) to only registered users or only the content owners.

So, how can we limit content visibility on different levels, for example

- PUBLIC: anybody can see the content, including anonymous
- INTERNAL: only registered users can see the content
- PRIVATE: only the creator can see the content

What would be the best way to implement this, it looks like RBAC does not have a straightforward way of dealing with this.

Comment: What do you mean by straightforward ? Handle this with yii2 is quite simple. What did you try actually ?

Comment: We used the method suggested in the Yii2 doc (security-authorization.md) and used three different read permission, but now we are a bit lost on how to use this permissions in an efficient way without writing code to check the access in the controller action. We thought the main advantage of the Yii2 RBAC implementation was to NOT have to change the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem can be solved by using [defaultScope](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html) in models. Thus, before giving the content, we can check the current role of the user data and give the necessary conditions.

```
public static function find()
{
    $userRoleArray = \Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser(Yii::$app->user->getId());
    $userRole = current($userRoleArray)->name;

    if ($userRole == 'admin') {
        return parent::find()->where("Your condition");
    } elseif ($userRole == 'moderator') {
        return parent::find()->where("Your condition");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a permission function and run in each function that will take user role as argument and returns true or redirect to not allowed page.

Here is something I tried but you can modify according to your need.

```
public function allowUser($min_level) { 
        //-1 no login required 0..3: admin level
        $userRole = //get user role;
        $current_level = -1;
        if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
            $current_level = 0;
        else
            $current_level = userRole;
        if ($min_level > $current_level) {
            $this->redirect(array("/pages/not-allowed"),true);
        }
    }
```